# Get token for Microsoft API with JWT

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

Reading [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-app-registration), you have to register your application using [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com).
Also, according to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate), you need **Application ID URI** to specify the scope parameter and **tenant_id** for the aud parameter in order to [generate the JWT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials).
The problem is : where do I find this informations?

I tried to use these without success :

```
scope : api://0adaa814-c4d4-4c09-ae8e-dd0535e9e931/.default
aud : https://login.microsoftonline.com/mldijon.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/oauth2/token
```

For more information here the error I get while trying to get a token :

> AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the
>   request or implied by any provided credentials.

And here the POST request I make to get it :

```
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 888bf937-31b4-166b-4d8d-339cd05e21ea

client_id=256e411c-bf42-4634-abaa-a7feafe6698a&scope=api%3A%2F%2F256e411c-bf42-4634-abaa-a7feafe6698a%2F.default&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJ4NXQiOiJKemdVM09ycWlqZVBFVjRGMlZLd3NFYW0rekk9IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiIyNTZlNDExYy1iZjQyLTQ2MzQtYWJhYS1hN2ZlYWZlNjY5OGEiLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczpcL1wvbG9naW4ubWljcm9zb2Z0b25saW5lLmNvbVwvbWxkaWpvbi5vbm1pY3Jvc29mdC5jb21cL29hdXRoMlwvdG9rZW4iLCJzdWIiOiIyNTZlNDExYy1iZjQyLTQ2MzQtYWJhYS1hN2ZlYWZlNjY5OGEiLCJleHAiOjE1MTEyNzI0MjYsImlhdCI6MTUxMTI2ODgyNiwibmJmIjoxNTExMjY4ODI2fQ.ZurlKZQ34FNPYLrAujzN6QOkZ9iufJMwVpkMU_gk53UOQqNk-Y_pFOf-OwwGRg9wCnfU46xZt2TiGj_3zLhHxsawg6VeI-tbt62onBiBfJCtTUXpedK23PLS0td7ss2oU7yziRmHDrGe3ZPmpMChnom2iLUNoZiZeAWgzdV47HGid7IJ8Je0fOglsvGvKLjRqC6Y5jJ2kaY6KDd8dhN4UgJjM-HoeGKYtNQ5dz9C8lPDD9_stejfkzDUtvCrFyOY9Cn5TmqZe-LxFW4i7imvriIQHRK1F30j7iWLDoB3aI9WN5Y0dTBl8_8bq83HE9fK5hWFmibt1zY4pclSGm8UNg&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? What Microsoft API are you trying to access? The error you are running into is likely because you are using "common" rather than a tenant specific endpoint. However, the rest of your post makes it look like you are very far off from what is correct.

Comment: I'm trying to access Office 365 API.    
Concerning the tenant's endpoint, is there something mentioning it in the doc ?

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the instructions here to get an access token to the Microsoft Graph.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20mail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

Note a few things:

- The `aud` value is implied to be `https://graph.microsoft.com` when it is not specified.
- The `scope` value is a one or more of the [permissions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference) defined by the Microsoft Graph.

Now the code above works specifically for User Sign In. There is a section about getting an access token without a user: [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

This follows this pattern:

```
// Line breaks are for legibility only.

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Note that this has `{tenant}` rather than `common` in the token url. This is because when you are getting a token without a user, you must specify the tenant endpoint you are trying to access. In the case of the user being present, we try to auto-discover the tenant endpoint, which is what the common endpoint does.

Let me know if this solves your problems.

Comment: Thank you, I'm now able to get a token, the key was to use {tenant} rather than common in the token url.

Comment: Now I have a 401 exception when I try to make an API call.    
I've tried to call https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events (after setting up the application's permissions Calendars.Read and Calendars.ReadWrite)

Comment: Did you redo admin consent? New permissions means you need to consent again

Comment: As I have only one test account, there is not any admin. May I do this with the same account?

Comment: Are you signing in with a user or using the credential flow? The me endpoint doesn't make sense unless you have a user signed in

Comment: I'm using client_credential flow. What endpoint should I use then? Can you give me a solid example?

Comment: Ok, I've managed to authorize my application with an admin account. But I still have a 401 error when I try to make my API call. I get my token with this url `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/oauth2/v2.0/token` and call this API url `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{account-address}/events`. In the response Headers, I have this `x-ms-diagnostics →2000001;reason="Token type is not known.";error_category="invalid_token"` Any idea?

Comment: I don't think that API supports the V2 tokens, which explains the error message too. You might need to use a legacy AAD Application registered in the Azure Portal. Or you should call the Microsoft Graph API for that information.

Comment: Ok I finally got it. I had to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` as scope parameter. Thanks for the help :)